# Anyone using unzip_file successfully? It uploads the zip but doesn't extract it!

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

When I call the WordPress unzip_file() function below, instead of actually extracting the zip, it merely moves it into the target folder.

When I trace $file and $to from includes/file.php I get:

```
file: C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/styles/myzip.zip 

To: C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/styles/
```

What am I missing?

```
<?php
require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');
require('../../../wp-admin/includes/file.php');
?>
<?php  
if (!is_user_logged_in()){
    die("You Must Be Logged In to Access This");
}
if( ! current_user_can('edit_files')) {
    die("Oops sorry you are not authorized to do this");
}
?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="fupload" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Install" onclick="doLoader();" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_FILES['fupload'])) {
    $filename = $_FILES['fupload']['name'];
    $source = $_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name'];
    $type = $_FILES['fupload']['type']; 
    $name = explode('.', $filename); 
    $target = TEMPLATEPATH.'/styles/';

    // permission settings for newly created folders
    $chmod = 0755;  

    $saved_file_location = $target . $filename;
    if (move_uploaded_file($source, $saved_file_location)) 
    {
        unzip_file($saved_file_location, $target);
    } 
    else 
    {
        die("There was a problem with the upload. Plese verify you have uploaded a valid zip file");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Any particular reason this is third time you create/delete essentially same question under different titles? :)

Comment: I suppose I just wanted to get it right after further testing and new data ;)

Comment: Do we get mulligans?

Comment: you can use the ZipArchive object of php. you can do a lot of stuffs with it. here's the link: http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a filesystem and setup that allows for direct access? If the filesystem object is expecting FTP credentials, then you may not get the results you're looking for without giving it the right username/password/server information.

Comment: testing on localhost with full admin access. I'm able to get this to work when using my own unzip function, I'm just trying to tap into the wordpress version since it offers more flexibility when ZipArchive is not present.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (move_uploaded_file($source, $saved_file_location)) 
    {
        WP_Filesystem();
        unzip_file($saved_file_location, $target);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the unzip hangs, it might be a bug in some versions of PHP. 
Shows up on my hosting account as: WordPress Update hangs, WordPress Plugin/Theme updates hang, and PHP unzip (without any calls to WordPress) hangs.

`$zip->extractTo($path.'/folder')` or `copy("zip://".$zipFullPath.'#'.$filename, $destPath.$destName)` both hang, no error message in system log, PHP log, or on screen.

Folders get created, no files in them.

See http://lcblog.lernerconsult.com/2013-php-unzip-bug-makes-wordpress-updates-hang/ for PHP code (without WordPress) and testing that demonstrates the bug is in PHP itself.

Changing my hosting account PHP versions, to PHP 5.3.24, from PHP 5.2.17, via a .htaccess configuration change, fixed the problem: PHP Unzip, WordPress Updates work.

Comment: Answers on WPSE should be more than a link to what looks to be almost certainly your site. That makes the post look more like advertising than it does an answer. And please format the minimal code you posted.